# Why is my function inside a rule in jQuery Validation Plugin not returning false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

In jQuery Validation Plugin I have a rule for an input field that should be set to false if a hidden input has val equal to 1, and true if 2.

I have made a function inside one of the rules for the input field, where I look for the hidden input val, and returning true or false based on the number. However, it is returning true no matter what, even though I can see it should be returning false. See [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cempshb2/18/)

HTML:

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="pick" value="1"/>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input name="user" id="user" type="text"/>
  <input type="Submit"/>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('form').validate({
    rules: {
    user: {
        required: true,
        email: function(){
          if($('input[name="pick"]').val() == 1){
            console.log('Email shold be false');
            return false;
          }else{
            return true;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Why is "return false" not working? I can see in the console that "Email should be set to false"

Note: This is just an example of what I am trying to achieve. I am going to have a lot more inputs and rule-changes. Also, the hidden input field is generated by other measures (Not two buttons like in the example). I know I could just make 2 forms, but I rather want to do it with 1, because there is going to be a lot of changes and that would require a lot of forms / double js code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"Why is my function inside a rule in jQuery Validation Plugin not returning false?"*

It's not.  The `email` rule is seeing your function in place of a boolean and interpreting its mere existence as "not `false`", thereby enabling the rule.

In order to use a function here, it needs to be inside of [the `depends` callback parameter](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules).

Also, since you need to get a boolean in the first place, there is no need for an if/else statement; just `return` the result of your conditional statement.

Flip the conditional to a "not equals" (`!=`), so the `email` rule is not enforced when the hidden value is `1`.

```
rules: {
    user: {
        required: true,
        email: {
            depends: function(element) {
                return ($('input[name="pick"]').val() != 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Working DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/v4bf1mvj/](https://jsfiddle.net/v4bf1mvj/)**

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set `email` to be a function (`email: function(){}`).

You should set the properties of the `email` object so that the framework can read what it needs to.

So to place your own function in `email` to validate (return true or false) you should do so like this:

```
$('form').validate({
            rules: {
                user: {
                    required: true,
                    email: {
                        depends: function () {
                            var checkValue = $('input[name="pick"]').val() == 1;
                            return checkValue;

                            // Or this - depending on your requirements.
                            // return !checkValue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```